# How does resultSet store values

Tags: java, sql

I'm running a query that loads into a ResultSet. When I'm creating my object from the ResultSet I use various get methods of the ResultSet. Does the ResultSet store all the values as Strings no matter what they're defined as in the DB? So if the result of a query is the number 1, can I call

```
rs.getString("result");
AND
rs.getInt("result");
```

?

Or does the get method of the ResultSet have to correspond to a correct type?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157476/resultset-behavior-with-mysql-database-does-it-store-all-rows-in-memory

Comment: @qqilihq:I said "POSSIBLE"

Comment: @Mr.Pandey:  Disagree as well.  That question and this question are tangentially related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is important here is the type of the variable that will receive the returned value.

For example, you can without any problem use rs.getString() in a column that return int values since numbers are valid string values ("1234", "23,45", etc.).

But you cannnot use rs.getInt() in a column with string values because the returned value will be not valid for a int variable.

MySQL help has more information about this:

> In general, any MySQL data type can be converted to a
> java.lang.String, and any numerical type can be converted to any of
> the Java numerical types, although round-off, overflow, or loss of
> precision may occur.
>
> These MySQL Data Types    Can always be converted to these Java types:
>
> - **CHAR, VARCHAR, BLOB, TEXT, ENUM, and SET**:   java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream, java.io.Reader, java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob
> - **FLOAT, REAL, DOUBLE PRECISION, NUMERIC, DECIMAL, TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INTEGER, BIGINT**: java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Short,    java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Long,
>   java.lang.Double,    java.math.BigDecimal
> - **DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP**:    java.lang.String, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp

[More info Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes and yes. You can get an INT from MySQL as a java.lang.String, *and* the types have mappings

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Hope this helps